# Using altgr-{/} for prev/next tab in Chromium

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, chromium

I've come across from OS X. I've got muscle memory for the following shortcuts in Chromium:

```
altgr-[  (back)
altgr-{  (prev tab)
altgr-}  (next tab)
```

Now, I know that you cannot change keyboard shortcuts in Chromium (easily), and the Chromium extensions only allow fairly restricted keyboard shortcuts.

However, there are keyboard shortcuts for the above actions, e.g. ctrl-PgDn for next tab.

Is it possible to bind a keyboard short cut to sending ctrl-PgDn to Chromium, so that I could use altgr-} (or say Ctrl-} or Hyper-} ) to switch to next tab?

I tried xdotool, but I couldn't get that to work. Moreover, it requires you to release the modifier keys, so that it can type it's own combination. I normally hold altgr+shift, and then use { and } to cycle through tabs. So xdotool didn't quite work for me.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 19.04, this can be achieved with autokey (available through the software centre). In autokey, set up a script

> keyboard.send_keys("<ctrl>+<np_page_down>")

and bind it to the keys that you like.